# Cannot open include file: 'cpprest/http_client.h'

Tags: c++, rest, visual-studio-2012, nuget-package

I'm trying to run c++ windows application using casablanca 'c++ rest sdk' for REST requests.
I've created new 'CLR Empty Project' (visual studio 2012) and added new item - 'Windows Form'. added some code and was able to see a form when running the projects.
now, I have installed the c++ rest sdk using NuGet, as the instructions tell. it all went successfully. the problem is that in order to use the 'c++ rest sdk' I've added these:

```
#include <cpprest/http_client.h>
#include <cpprest/filestream.h>
```

and it doesn't find those files.
I'm getting

```
fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'cpprest/http_client.h': No   such file or directory
```

Project screenshot:
[image: project screenshot]

thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check if you have set up the include directories for the headers. You can do it under project properties -> Configuration Properties -> C/C++ -> General -> Additional Include Directories.

Comment: it's empty. when clicking 'edit' I see empty list and "Inherit from parent..." is checked. what supposed to be there?

Comment: You have to add the directory where the "cpprest" folder is. That way, the compiler would know where to search for cpprest/http_client.h. The #include <xxxxxx.h> searches in the additional include directories, and the #include "xxxxx.h" searches in the current project directory only.

Comment: thanks. it actually helped. but then I ran into other problem. thanks anyway.

Comment: In case a user is using Qt as a development environment, you need to add the path to the "cpprestsdk_xx-XX" in your .pro file for both "include" and "lib" folder of "cpprestsdk" or to your properties file in case you are using any other development env.

Answer (score 6):

you have to include this path :

C:\YourProject\packages\cpprestsdk.v140.windesktop.msvcstl.dyn.rt-dyn.2.8.0\build\native\include

and:

C:\YourProject\packages\cpprestsdk.v140.windesktop.msvcstl.dyn.rt-dyn.2.8.0\lib

I've got the same issue after I added the NuGet package. The include and lib folders are not linked automatically as the description says.

Answer (score 0):

I have faced the same problems like you. 
Even i set my project properties manually, i could see linking errors.

And i could find an article on their official forum.

https://casablanca.codeplex.com/discussions/644534

> Yes, we've removed VS 2012 binaries from the package. I recommend
>   trying out VS 2015 community, which can be downloaded for free from:
>   https://www.visualstudio.com/downloads/download-visual-studio-vs.

I have tested it on the same way on VS2015 community IDE.
The package is working perfectly.

Comment: and also you have to notice that they are not offering static libraries. therefore, your application is needed to be set 'MD/MDd'.