# Microsoft/CppRestSDK Casablanca, Visual Studio 2017

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, cpprest-sdk, external-dependencies

**The Goal**

Build a simple [cpprestsdk](https://github.com/Microsoft/cpprestsdk) example in Visual Studio.

**What I've done so far**

Following the guidelines on the [wiki](https://github.com/Microsoft/cpprestsdk/wiki/), I'm able to build a working example by cloning the git repository. But, I want to be able to link, include and setup the project myself and kind of figure out things from there.

Using [vcpkg](https://github.com/Microsoft/cpprestsdk/wiki/Getting-Started-Tutorial) to download and compile all the external dependencies and, following the general workflow of Visual Studio, adding the external libraries, including the headers and copying the DLLs, I'm able to compile and, almost run the executable.

**Error no:1**

While trying to compile [this](https://github.com/Microsoft/cpprestsdk/wiki/Getting-Started-Tutorial) getting started example

```
pplx::task<void> requestTask = fstream::open_ostream(U("results.html")).
    then([=](ostream outFile) {...}
```

Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error (active)  E0312   no suitable user-defined conversion from Concurrency::task< Concurrency::details
::_BadContinuationParamType >" to "Concurrency::task< void >"

**Error no:2**

Currently I'm unable to get this far, but I got an alignment error from xmemory0.h, while trying to make a simple get request.

**What I'm asking for**

After getting the alignment error, I assumed it had something to do with Unicode. How would I go about setting up Unicode in Visual Studio?

After trying to understand what's going on with libraries and dll's. How would I go about setting my projects up (file structure, project settings etc.) in Visual Studio?

Is there any article I can read about stepping up my VC++ game?

Thanks, apologies for my messy question...

Answer (score 1):

For Error no:1,
you can make the following change:

```
return concurrency::task<size_t>(response.body().read_to_end(fileStream->streambuf()));

//return response.body().read_to_end(fileStream->streambuf());
```

Answer (score 0):

For setting up Unicode:
Project>Properties>General>Project Defaults>Character Set.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SxSZa.png)
though after everything resolves, there are build errors as still posted in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29658672/cannot-open-include-file-cpprest-http-client-h/51318735#51318735) thread